# If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\overline{\lambda}$ must be an eigenvalue of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is this true or false?

If $A$ is an n by n Real matrix, then if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A, then $\overline{\lambda}$ must an eigenvalue of $A$

There is a theorem say that, if $A$ has a Non-real eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\overline{\lambda}$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$,
so this statement is true??  since all conjugate of real is just it self?

Comment: The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, so the non-real ones occur in conjugate pairs.

Comment: yes, I know. so the statement is true then? thank you

Comment: Yes, of course it's true.

Answer (score 1):

$Ax=\lambda x \to \overline{Ax}=\overline{\lambda x} \to A \overline{x} = \overline{\lambda} \overline{x} \to Ay = \overline{\lambda} y$